# Filtering time in Excel

Tags: excel, time, filter

I am having trouble filtering a column of times that used to work prior to today.

In column B1 was the format `DD-MM-YY HH:MM:SS AM/PM` so on column C1, I converted it into the format `HH:MM:SS AM/PM` and further pasted as value. I
autofilled till `B1:B & lastrow`, moved `C:C` to `B:B` and deleted column `B:B` as the purpose was served to get it converted to time only.

[image]

But later when I applied a filter on the time column B1 as shown below it does not give any results.

No code as yet as its just an Excel filter. I will write VBA if this works.

This filter should enable me to find the time cells ranging from specific time to specific time.

Comment: Please, edit your post, as you did not attach anything.

Comment: It sounds like you've moved from a true date/time format to text that looks like time.

Comment: The first time which is 8:21:00 PM
was earier 27-06-2019  8:21:00 PM which I converted via TEXT function as =TEXT(B2,"HH:MM:SS AM/PM")
and pasted as value now in true sense it is as 08:21:00 PM (as seen in formula bar)

Comment: If you use TEXT, it is now *text that looks like time*. Time filters don't work on text.

Comment: So any suggestion friends?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `TEXT`, the result is *text that looks like time*. Time filters don't work on text.

Here is a simple way to extract just the time value, with `INT` to remove the date portion of the date/time. A true time is a *number*, to which you can apply time formatting.

[image]

Comment: Perfect @BigBen <3
Thanks a million!!

Comment: And may I ask how to filter the column with data like, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss" & "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm"?

http://prntscr.com/p9s3t0